# How to remove an object from Arraylist by using contains

Tags: java, collections

I have added some objects to list. I want to remove an object, if it satisfies some condition.

**E.g:** In my list, I have object as follows

`[test/te,str1,str2]`

Scenario: No, I want to remove object which contains `test`

```
  List<Object> Extraprimitivesintarget = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if(ens2.size()!=0)
                {
                    HashSet s1=null;
                    HashSet s2=null;

                    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en1 : ens1) {
                        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en2 : ens2)
                        {
                            s1=new HashSet<>();
                            s1.add(en1.getKey());
                            s2=new HashSet<>();
                            s2.add(en2.getKey());
                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println("S1 is:"+s1);
                    //System.out.println("S2 is:"+s2);

                    Set<String> diff=Sets.symmetricDifference(s1, s2);
                    for(String difference:diff)
                    {

                        if(ens1.toString().contains(difference)&&!ens2.toString().contains(difference))
                        {
                            Extraprimitivesintarget.add(parentPath1+"/"+difference);
                        }
                        else if(ens2.toString().contains(difference)&&!ens1.toString().contains(difference))
                        {
                            Extraprimitivesintarget.add(parentpath2+"/"+difference);
                        }

                        **if(ens1.toString().contains(difference)&&ens2.toString().contains(difference)){
                            Extraprimitivesintarget.remove(difference);
                            System.out.println(Extraprimitivesintarget);
                        }**
                    }
```

Comment: What problem do you encounter? Simply iterate over your list, check each element and remove if you found a match. Use an iterator to iterate over the list to avoid ConcurrentModificationExcpetions.

Comment: You haven't explained the problem

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @Sreenath Reddy I cannot see how ens1 and ens2 are in the scope of your if statements

Comment: The question and the given program is not clear enough please update it once reviewed the given answers as we can help you by some assumptions only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your question is not clear enough. If you want to remove items from a list by some specific text. Try the below one. I hope it will help you.

**RemoveItemsFromListByContains.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class RemoveItemsFromListByContains {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creating an Empty Integer ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("test/te");
        list.add("str1");
        list.add("str2");
        // Print list of items before remove
        System.out.println(list);

        removeItemByContainStr(list, "test");

        // Print list of items after removed
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void removeItemByContainStr(ArrayList<String> list, String containStr) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String str = (String) iterator.next();
            if (str.contains(containStr)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an element from `List`,having a try using the below code.

```
@Test
public void test001() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Testt");
    list.add("TsT");
    list.add("test");
    list.add("tes");
    list.add("tesA");
    list.add("tesc");

    //in JAVA 8
    System.out.println("before removing" + list);
    list.removeIf(l -> "test".equals(l));//remove "test" element
    System.out.println("after removing" + list);

    //before JAVA 8
    System.out.println("before removing" + list);
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String s = iterator.next();
        if ("tes".equals(s)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("after removing" + list);
}
```

Comment: This program will not help him to remove the text "Atest" as Sreenath Reddy mentioned a Scenario: To remove the object which contains "test".